# Reading from a piped stream

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to figure out the best way to read from a piped stream. Basically, I have a file on my computer that I would like to read from, pipe it through a crypto cipher and then upload it to an endpoint. I'm using the `form-data` package which helps create mutli-part form requests by accepting a ReadableStream. But I'm not sure the best way to pipe the readable stream to the cipher and still give the package a readable stream from that pipe without first writing that readable stream to a file and then reading from that file.

Current Code:

```
let myStream = fs.createReadStream('./myfile.txt'),
form = new FormData();
form.append('contents', myStream);
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) Class of the Node js Stream API.

The main thing here is understanding that transform stream is kind of a duplex, that is both readable and writable.

Basically, your "streams-scheme"  will look like:

```
read from file -> transform with cipher -> pipe to form-data
```